# Check for duplicates of an array of data

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to remove any duplicates of e-mails that get come from `$row->guestE-mail`

What is the best way to do this?  I have seen so many different answers

**Code:**

```
foreach ($results->data as $row) {
    $emails[] = $row->guestEmail;

    //Check for e-mails to be removed

    $blacklistedEmails = false;

    foreach ($blacklist as $b) {

        if (stripos($row->guestEmail, $b) !== false && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->endDate)) == $date) {
            $blacklistedEmails = true;
            ++$blacklistCounts[$b];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$blacklistedEmails && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->endDate)) == $date) {

        $guests[] = array(
            'FirstName' => $row->guestFirstName,
            'LastName' => $row->guestLastName,
            'email' => $row->guestEmail,
            'country' => $row->guestCountry,
            'check-in_date' => $row->startDate,
            'check-out_date' => $row->endDate,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Try: `array_unique(array_column($results->data, 'guestEmail'))`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya How would I use that within the code?

Comment: Can you explain your requirements further ? Do you want to not consider the `$row` in which a duplicate `guestEmail` is there (one which has appeared in a previous value already) ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a temp variable to store the `guestEmail` values.
- Using [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function inside the loop, check if this email already exists in the temp variable or not. If yes, ignore further processing and `continue` to next.

Try the following:

```
// temp variable to store all the emails coming in loop
$emails = array();

foreach ($results->data as $row) {

    $guestEmail = $row->guestEmail;

    // check if the guestEmail of this row already exists or not
    if ( in_array($guestEmail, $emails) ) {
        // Duplicate email found
        // continue to next row
        continue;
    }

    // add this row's guestEmail to temp array
    $emails[] = $guestEmail;

    /**
     Here goes your blaclisted emails related code
     **/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as well:

```
$emails = ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com', 'email3@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com'];

$new = [];

foreach($emails as $email) {
    if(!in_array($email, $new)) {
        array_push($new, $email);
    }
}

print_r($new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [array_unique](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). No need to reprogram that function.

```
foreach ($results->data as $row) {
$emails[] = $row->guestEmail;

array_unique($emails); // <--- Insert here

//Check for e-mails to be removed

$blacklistedEmails = false;

foreach ($blacklist as $b) {

    if (stripos($row->guestEmail, $b) !== false && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->endDate)) == $date) {
        $blacklistedEmails = true;
        ++$blacklistCounts[$b];
        break;
    }
}

if (!$blacklistedEmails && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->endDate)) == $date) {

    $guests[] = array(
        'FirstName' => $row->guestFirstName,
        'LastName' => $row->guestLastName,
        'email' => $row->guestEmail,
        'country' => $row->guestCountry,
        'check-in_date' => $row->startDate,
        'check-out_date' => $row->endDate,
    );
}
}
```